# Locate table cell containing Content Control

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Objective**

I have a table in Word with 2 columns. The first has a drop down Content Control.

I would like to populate the second column with text, the value of which depends on the option selected.

**Question**

Is it possible to get the cell reference that contains the clicked content control? I plan to use that to target the next column with the content.  I'm thinking of something like this:

```
    Dim oCell As Cell
    oCel = 'some way to get cell reference containing the ContentControl here
    Dim curCellRow, curCellCol, targetCellRow, targetCellCol As Integer
    curCellRow = oCell.Row
    curCellCol = oCell.Column
    targetCellRow = curCellRow
    targetCellCol = curCellCol + 1

    Dim NewCellContents As String
    NewCellContents = "Sample Content for this cell"

    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(targetCellRow, targetCellCol).Range.Text = NewCellContents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out - here's how I did it:

```
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Long
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    RowNum = Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex
    ColNum = Selection.Cells(1).ColumnIndex
    MsgBox "Row = " & RowNum & vbCr & _
    "Column = " & ColNum
    Else
    MsgBox "Not in table"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and used the following code in the ContentControlOnExit event in ThisDocument.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim TableNum As Long, RowNum As Long, ColNum As Long
If ContentControl.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    TableNum = Me.Range(0, ContentControl.Range.End).Tables.Count
    RowNum = ContentControl.Range.Information(wdStartOfRangeRowNumber)
    ColNum = ContentControl.Range.Information(wdStartOfRangeColumnNumber)
End If
' more code
End Sub
```